# Is the airspeed different between above and under the wings?

Tags: aerodynamics, wind

I heard that when an airplane is flying, air speed or air pressure is higher under the wings. Is it true?

Comment: For more on this, see [How do wings generate lift?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16193/998)

Comment: Yes air travels slower under the wing and faster over the wing, which creating a high pressure under the wing and a low pressure above the wing then the high pressure pushes up on the bottom part of the wing and that's how airplanes generate lift.

Comment: [How wings really work.](http://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/how-wings-really-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a subsonic attached flow over the cambered airfoil (or a symmetric one at an angle of attack), the airflow speed is higher over the wing and pressure is lower. It is the other way around on the lower surface.

[image: Airflow over the wing]

Source: virtualskies.arc.nasa.gov

Note that this is just the mechanics of the flow over the wing. This is *not* an explanation of lift.

Comment: The diagram is a little misleading because it looks like the lower airflow is deflected upwards by the wing, and the stationary point is higher than the trailing edge. This would produce negative lift.

Comment: The green arrow resembles the lift force.

Comment: I thought that horse named "equal transit time" had been beaten into falsehood.

Comment: @BillOer Certainly, at least to my knowledge, the "equal transit time" is no longer believed to be true, but I can't see anything about the answer that infers "equal transit time". Even if one considers the blue arrows that start at a the same point in front of the wing as time or velocity vectors, note that the top arrow ends before the bottom arrow.

Comment: Once again, this is *not* an explanation for lift. It would be a gross oversimplification and will confuse things. That is why I added that disclaimer. Also, I'm not inferring anything that even remotely says 'equal transit time'. I'm just saying that the pressure above the wing is lower and higher below.

Comment: @Terry, that airflow picture looks much like those I've seen for "equal transit time" explanations. But you're right, nothing aeroalias said implied equal transit time.