# Where does the lift act on a B747-400 wing when the aircraft flies straight and level?

Tags: lift, boeing-747

I'm doing a math exercise and I'd like to understand:

- Where does lift act overall on the wing of a B747-400 when the aircraft flies straight and level at its cruise speed.
- Which parameters, if any, may significantly affect the location of this point.

I'd appreciate if you share a reference document.

Comment: For almost any simulation (short of an advanced fluid dynamics simulator), wing lift is centered at the thickest part of the wing, which is where the 1st derivative of the upper-edge is 0.

Comment: The angle of attack does not have anything to do with the horizon; it is 0 when the angle of the wing chord is equal to the angle of the wind passing the wing

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16193/how-do-wings-generate-lift

Comment: Welcome! I'll edit your question so that it doesn't attract downvotes, it you are unsatisfied with the adjustments you can always restore your version (rollback) using the edited... link at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need some sort of a reference document. Otherwise, i cannot use the information. Thanks!

Comment: Getting closer to the transonic regime modifies the application point.

Comment: I am sorry, but i have no idea what that means. Could you dumb it down and explain?