Why does flow separation cause a loss of lift, considering the low pressure is the cause of lift above the wing?
When the flow separates, the main stream of air is no longer passing by the upper surface of the wing. Usually this means that the air pressure will decrease above the wing, because the freestream flow can't 'get' to the area behind the wing (AKA the stalled area).

Something else necessary to this question :
When the flow turns downwards over the upper surface of a wing like you can see in the picture below, that doesn't necessarily make lift¹.

The low pressure created from this turning on top of the wing is what makes the lift¹. According to the last comment of this answer on Physics.SE.

The pressure difference creates the force (not the bending). The reasoning of why the pressure difference is created is more complex.


Back to the main question, now knowing these 2 things:

The turning of this flow doesn't create the lift, only the low pressure (which technically means that the turning does create the lift, but it does so by creating the low pressure)

There is low pressure created in the stalled area of wing


So if there is low pressure created in the stalled area of a wing anyways, and all that the flow turning downwards over the wing does is create low pressure, why does lift decrease when flow separates?
The way that I see it is that if the stalled area is low pressure, and all the flow turning downwards over the wing does is make low pressure, then why does the lift change if there is still low pressure above the wing in both cases?
(The actual magnitude of the low pressure might be different in a stall compared to the low pressure created from the flow turning downwards over the wing, which isn't something I considered)

So in case the question wasn't exactly obvious, why does the flow separating suddenly decrease the lift, given the information above?
¹: Even though I linked a source I am not 100% sure, although I see no other way for the flow turning to make lift, so I might be mistaken.

Does this answer your question?  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/55163/why-does-a-stall-decrease-lift-rather-than-increasing-it?rq=1

@MichaelHall That top answer is actually what sparked this question. The answer states that the air that flows over the wing needs to get it's momentum vector pointed down slightly, but as stated in my question, the 'bending' of air doesn't create the lift (I don't think) so that doesn't really help.

@MichaelHall Also, do you know why this is getting downvoted? I provided sources, and some of the statements I knew I could be mistaken about I made a disclaimer at the bottom for. If I know what people think is wrong with this question I would be more than happy to edit it.

There are many questions here about lift and stalls.  Look up "downwash" and google Newton's 3rd law of motion.  The downvotes are likely for lack of any real effort.

@MichaelHall It might not reflect in my question, but I usually do quite a bit of research before asking, and that includes browsing this site. All of the other sources I found assumed the downward movement of air over the wing was  a cause of lift, however as stated with a source, that isn’t 100% accurate. Also, if you look at the help center, you’re supposed to downvote when there is a lack of research effort or the question doesn’t provide enough information to be answerable. In my question, I provided a source to back up my claim, and I believe that there was plenty of information.

Ok, just my opinion, but it feels like you are beating a dead horse...

@MichaelHall I can see where you’re coming from, but maybe when I figure out this question it will be obvious why it’s different.

Look at the first smoke trail over the airfoil, see how uniform, even and close it is to the surface? That is "laminar" flow and it places fast flowing air as close to the upper surface of the airfoil as you can get developing the greatest lift. Now consider that flow separated and turbulent mixing fast and slow air near the airfoil surface. the average velocity across the upper surface will be greatly reduced, reducing lift. Understand separation doesn't happen all-at-once. It will begin near the trailing edge and move forward, and from the wing-root out. (generally)

This is an interesting question. Perhaps a good way to break it down:

The local shape of the airfoil forces turning of the air packets
Due to the turning of the air packets, the local pressure decreases
The local pressure acts on the surface of the wing (and this is how the force is transferred from the air to the wing)
The sum of the forces on the surface combines to lift & drag.

If we look at the example of the cylinder, here for different Reynolds numbers.

Source
We then take a closer look at separated vs not-separted.
We therefore zoom in on the first two images. Here the first image has no separation, whereas the second has flow separation. Have a closer look at the blue and red streamlines, and then specifically in the area I marked with a circle.
You can see that the red line (the one that is separated) has much less curvature in that area than the blue one. As a consequence, the pressure in that area will not be as low as it is in the blue case.

Source: Edit of the above image
Flow separation on the wing has the same effect (see the images below), it reduces the curving of the air packets, thereby reducing the negative pressure, and reducing the amount of lift generated.

Source

I see. So the pressure of separated flow is high than that of attached flow, like you said with your example. If you use that logic, how does flow separation create more drag? If the pressure is higher with separated flow behind an object, why would it create more drag than attached flow?

(If that doesn’t make sense I can try to explain it better)

I think that's another question to ask. The direct relationship between curvature and pressure only holds for inviscid flows (but can be useful in viscous flows). Drag in separated flow is dominated by viscous effects (to understand why drag is larger, look at the size of the 'dead water' region in Peter's answer).

I see. So by viscous effects do you mean the turbulence ‘mixing’ the flow above the wing to where the wing has to transfer more of its energy to the surrounding air?

@Wyatt I would recommend you look at Fundamentals of Aerodynamics, by John. D. Anderson, specifically p.390-393. It talks about exactly this.
This book is a great reference to learn about the principles of aerodynamics, and it would be a great starting point for your learning journey. It is a great resource, with the information structured coherently, which I think will benefit you greatly.

Oh interesting, I actually have that book. I will take a look when I can.

To illustrate the effect of flow separation on lift, consider what the flow outside of the boundary layer "sees" when flowing around the wing. At low angle of attack flow is attached, the boundary layer stays thin and the flowlines follow the contour of the wing, give and take the few millimeters of boundary layer.
At high angle of attack the flow separates on the upper rear wing and the boundary layer grows massively, filled up by a turbulent deadwater which presents a quite different airfoil to the outside flow. Since the thickening only happens on the upper side, the effective angle of attack of this wing-plus-deadwater airfoil is quite a bit lower than the geometric angle of attack of the original airfoil
In the sketch below you will see the airfoil at two different angles of attack (grey), the flowlines around both (blue) and the boundary layer air (red). The difference should be easy to spot.

The wing with separated flow still produces considerable lift, but much less than what the pure wing would be capable of if the flow would be inviscid (so all the red stuff would be missing in those sketches).
BTW, that dead water will be "eaten up" by the outside flow by the same mechanism which created the boundary layer: Shear will eventually equalise the speed of all the air behind the wing.

Most of the lift force is from the large package of air that was induced to move down by the wing's passage, not so much from the "suction" of the LP area pulling the wing up. The low pressure area and its distribution profile, moving in a smooth non chaotic manner, is what induces this movement, extending several chords above the wing (it's why you put spoilers on top to kill lift).
When a wing stalls, the low pressure region is still there, but because it's turbulent, its ability to induce a large package of air above it to move down is destroyed, and the total mass of air being moved down is limited to air that is directly deflected by the wing itself (plus what pressure differential there is).

If you were to look at it on a molecular level where the LP area above the wing turns the flow: If the flow were not to turn, then there would be a complete vacuum. The flow does turn because the LP forces it to turn. On a molecular level, the area of more air molecules would travel into the LP area above the wing where there is less air molecules. It’s like the atmosphere pressure is bending the air over the wing, and not the low pressure. You could also look at it as low pressure never pulls anything. When I have more time, I will be explaining this better, in case it doesn’t make sense.

Not only the turbulence limits the contribution of the area to the downwash, but also the adverse velocity gradient close to the airfoil in the separation bubble actually opposes to the downwash.

@mins I don’t think you were intending to answer my whole question with that comment, but you just might’ve! So if I’m understanding you correctly, (or at least part of what you said) the turbulent air mixes the flow in the stalled area, so the pressure isn’t able to be as low as it would without the turbulence? Essentially, the low pressure air in the stalled area is forced out by the turbulence mixing the air.

@mins With a few of the other answers put together, I think I understand that part now. However, using the same logic that you just explained, why would separation cause a drag increase? I could definitely see the L/D ratio being changed, but why would the separation itself change the drag?

@mins “In the turbulent boundary layer the pressure gradient close to the airfoil is larger” - If you don’t mind answering, why is that the case? Why would turbulence change any pressure gradients?

@Wyatt: Turbulence changes velocities and introduces negative velocities (adverse gradient). To simplify, say pressure is linked to velocity (by Bernoulli's principle) also in the turbulent BL. Velocities in the two BL are shown here. Y is the height in the BL (0=wall, 1=outer limit of BL) and X is the fraction of free stream velocity U0 at this height. You see the steeper curve for the TBL (source). I suggest we continue in the chat for more clarifications.

@mins That actually does make sense, thanks. Here is the chat room that I just created.


So if there is low pressure created in the stalled area of a wing anyways, and all that the flow turning downwards over the wing does is create low pressure, why does lift decrease when flow separates?

The premise of your question is not correct.
The following picture (source) shows how on an airfoil the pressure distribution changes with the AoA:

According to the source, this particular airfoil stalls at 11° so that the plots in the middle and on the right are for stalled conditions.
As you can see, when the airfoil stalls the pressure on the upper surface (lower part of the plots) becomes flat and the peak of suction around its leading edge (seen on the left plot) just disappears.

I see. The air accelerating over the upper surface is what causes the suction in your picture. When you increase AoA, won’t the upper surface also become lower pressure because of the higher AoA regardless of the acceleration of air? See here to see what I am talking about.

Basically, the suction peak from the accelerating air can’t be greater than the high pressure that did the accelerating of that air. Then also, as the link says, the high pressure on the front of an object (the lower surface of an airfoil at high AoA) will have an equal but opposite pressure on the back of the object (the upper surface of the airfoil at high AoA).

If that didn’t help, essentially if you have an airfoil at high AoA to where the lower surface is contacting free stream air, the high pressure that creates will be mirrored by an equal but opposite low pressure on the other side.

"the high pressure on the lower surface of an airfoil at high AoA will have an equal but opposite pressure on the upper surface of the airfoil" not really since the flow on the upper\opposite side is fully detached and doesn't follow the shape of the airfoil. The high pressure on the side facing the flow wouldn't be compensated for low pressure on the shadowed side. Intuitively: if that were true then drag would be zero...

Consider the low pressure area in terms of the Bernoulli principle, thinking of the average speed of those molecules as they move from that point normal to the relative wind and the trailing edge. Averaged across the wing, turbulent air moves slower, with a corresponding higher pressure.
Assume smooth flow across the underside of the wing. A smooth flow across the upper surface would have a longer path, and motion parallel to the wing surface at any point. However, a turbulent flow contains some molecules moving away from the wing, and others angling toward the wing. It is all very messy or noisy: overall slower (with higher pressure) than when the airflow is smooth.

"the upper surface would have a longer path" length is totally unrelated to the problem, and this assertion is wrong for an airfoil without camber. Part of the equal transit time fallacy.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
